# Count of processes that are active in a python tornado app

Tags: python, tornado, python-asyncio

I'm starting a tornado app as below. For now i'm trying to provide as much as 4 forks or processes reading it from some config files.

```
application = tornado.web.Application([
(r"/", hello),],debug=False)
server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(application)
server.bind(1234)  # port
server.start(4) 
tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Is there any possible way to get the number of active processes that is running at any point of time?
Reading the documentation of tornado did not give me any valuable inputs.

Answer (score 1):

No, you'll need to use external monitoring tools for this. You know there should be 4 processes running, because you called `start(4)`, but once they're started the child processes don't know anything about each other.

Comment: What would be the use of 
    tornado.ioloop.thread._count()

Will this not give us the number of threads running at any point of time? Also is there any python based library that can be used to monitor the active number of threads.

Comment: Processes and threads are different. This question is about processes, but `thread._count()` counts threads. (note that the `thread` module here comes from the python standard library and is not a part of tornado. The fact that it can be accessed as `tornado.ioloop.thread` is an unsupported implementation detail).